# Creating and using SurfaceTexture in single buffered mode in view heirarchy

Tags: android, surfaceview, textureview, android-graphics

I am creating a custom view and setting a SurfaceTexture in single buffered mode as follows:

```
public class CustomTextureView extends TextureView
{
    public CustomTextureView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        initializeView();
    }

    public void initializeView()
    {
        mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(mSingleBuffered);
        setSurfaceTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
        setSurfaceTextureListener(new CustomSurfaceTextureListener(this));
    }
}
```

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175718927 post tells not to use `TextureView` with single buffered `SurfaceTexture`. I wanted to know for what reason it is as it is not mentioned in the documentation. Also, is there a way that I can create a single buffered `SurfaceTexture` and create a `view hierarchy` ?